# Where do I place the throws exception in chained overloaded constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

Do I need to place the throws clause on each constructor or just the final overloaded constructor being passed to the super class?

```
  //Constructors
  public ManufacturedPart(){
    this(0, null, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  public ManufacturedPart(int id){
    this(id, null, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  public ManufacturedPart(int id, double lCost, double mCost){
    this(id, null, 0, lCost, mCost);
  }
  public ManufacturedPart(int id, String desc, double sellPrice, double lCost, double mCost){
    super(id, desc, sellPrice);
    setLaborCost(lcost);
    setMaterialCost(mCost);
  }

  //Set Labor Cost
  public void setLaborCost(double lCost) throws InvalidProductionArgumentException {
    if(lCost < 0)
      throw(new InvalidProductionArgumentException("Labor cost can't be less than 0"));
    else if(lCost >= 0)
      laborCost = lCost;
  }

  //Set Material Cost
  public void setMaterialCost(double mCost) throws InvalidProductionArgumentException {
    if(mCost < 0)
      throw(new InvalidProductionArgumentException("Material cost can't be less than 0"));
    else if(mCost >= 0)
      materialCost = mCost;
  }
```

Comment: You have to handle every exception thrown by the methods called in your method, either by catching or adding `throws`; constructors are "special" methods, but not exempt from this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to place the throws clause on each constructor or just the final overloaded constructor being passed to the super class?

You need to place it on every constructor where this exception is possible. e.g.

```
public ManufacturedPart(int id) { // thrown not possible
     this(id, null, 0, 0, 0);
}

public ManufacturedPart(int id, double lCost, double mCost) 
         throws InvalidProductionArgumentException  { // it could happen here
    this(id, null, 0, lCost, mCost);
}
```

If the exception is a checked exception you need to refactor this so you don't have to handle checked exception which can't happen.

```
public ManufacturedPart(int id) { // thrown not possible
     super(id, null, 0); // use super instead of a constructor which throws an exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all four constructors call a method that throws `InvalidProductionArgumentException` (either directly or indirectly, by calling another constructor) and none of them handle that exception, all must have a `throws InvalidProductionArgumentException` clause.

This is assuming `InvalidProductionArgumentException` is a checked exception.

Comment: But the constructors are chained using the this() clause to the final (4th) constructor that then passes it back to the super class with all the info? So just on the final chained overloaded constructor or on each one that might cause the exception?

Comment: @SephCordovano No matter the cause, at least two of your constructors could throw that exception.

Comment: @SephCordovano The 4th constructor calls `setLaborCost` and `setMaterialCost`. Both of them have a `throws InvalidProductionArgumentException` clause. This means the 4th constructor must have a `throws InvalidProductionArgumentException` clause (unless it catches that exception and handles it internally). Since the other constructors call the 4th constructor, they must also have a `throws InvalidProductionArgumentException` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle every checked exception thrown by the methods called in your method, either by catching or adding `throws`; constructors are "special" methods, but not exempt from this rule.

So, if a constructor calls a method which `throws InvalidProductionArgumentException`, then that constructor must either `catch (InvalidProductionArgumentException e)` (or a super type) in the constructor body, or add `throws InvalidProductionArgumentException` (or a super type) to the constructor signature.

If you invoke that constructor from another constructor, and you opted to add `throws` to the "invoked" constructor, then the "invoking" constructor must declare that it `throws` the exception too.

---

If `InvalidProductionArgumentException` is an unchecked exception (i.e. it extends `RuntimeException` directly or indirectly), you don't need to explicitly handle the exception at all.

Comment: You can't `catch` exceptions thrown on a `this( ... )` call.

Comment: Huh, never knew. Makes sense though, now I stop and think for a second. Updated.

Comment: I knew because I tried until I realised why that shouldn't work. ;)